# CCRepeatForever do not repeat action in sequence

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-2.x

i have some code sentences

```
CCSequence* seq2 = CCSequence::create(CCCallFunc::create(_clawNode, callfunc_selector(ClawNode::swing))
                                              , CCDelayTime::create(1.6)
                                              , CCCallFunc::create(_clawNode, callfunc_selector(ClawNode::dig))
                                              , CCDelayTime::create(0.1)
                                              , NULL
                                              );
        _clawNode->runAction(CCRepeatForever::create(seq2));
```

The problem is that the CCRepeatForever do not repeat action in sequence, it just do it 1 time. Anyone knows how to fix this issue?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selector target object in `CCCallFunc` should be `CCLayer` in which your node is added. Therefore you should use like :

```
CCSequence* seq2 = CCSequence::create(CCCallFunc::create(this, callfunc_selector(ClawNode::swing))
                                              , CCDelayTime::create(1.6)
                                              , CCCallFunc::create(this, callfunc_selector(ClawNode::dig))
                                              , CCDelayTime::create(0.1)
                                              , NULL
                                              );
        _clawNode->runAction(CCRepeatForever::create(seq2));
```

Apart from this your code is fine. You might check if anywhere else if you are stopping actions of the Node in callback functions.

Comment: if I change "_clawNode" with "this", the screen will swing instead of my claw.